# Android Alarm Dismissal causes crash

Tags: android, alarm

what am i trying to do is to dismiss the alarm when it detect the smile. first when the alarm is ringing, it will go to this class, AlarmScreen.java. Then the user will click the smile button to open of the second activity that is MainActivity.java where it will open up the camera activity.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(AlarmScreen.this, AlarmManagerHelper.class);
    pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(AlarmScreen.this, 0, alarmIntent, 0);


    //Setup layout
    this.setContentView(R.layout.activity_alarm_screen);

    String name = getIntent().getStringExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.NAME);
    int timeHour = getIntent().getIntExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.TIME_HOUR, 0);
    int timeMinute = getIntent().getIntExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.TIME_MINUTE, 0);
    String tone = getIntent().getStringExtra(AlarmManagerHelper.TONE);

    TextView tvName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_name);
    tvName.setText(name);

    TextView tvTime = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_time);
    tvTime.setText(String.format("%02d : %02d", timeHour, timeMinute));

    Button dismissButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_button);
    dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            finish();
        }
    });

    Button camera = (Button) findViewById(R.id.camera);
    camera.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {


            Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


public void stopAlarm() {

    Button dismissButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.alarm_screen_button);
    dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            mPlayer.stop();
            finish();
        }
    });
}

    mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
    try {
        if (tone != null && !tone.equals("")) {
            Uri toneUri = Uri.parse(tone);
            if (toneUri != null) {
                mPlayer.setDataSource(this, toneUri);
                mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_ALARM);
                mPlayer.setLooping(true);
                mPlayer.prepare();
                mPlayer.start();
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

this is the MainActivity.java class where all the detection occur here.

```
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
    int surfaceWidth = mPreview.getWidth();
    int surfaceHeight = mPreview.getHeight();
    faceProc.normalizeCoordinates(surfaceWidth, surfaceHeight);
    numFaces = faceProc.getNumFaces();
    int dRotation = display.getRotation();
    PREVIEW_ROTATION_ANGLE angleEnum = PREVIEW_ROTATION_ANGLE.ROT_0;

    if (numFaces > 0) {
        System.out.println("face detected");
        Log.d("TAG", "Face Detected");
        faceArray = faceProc.getFaceData();
        preview.removeView(drawView);
        drawView = new DrawView(this, faceArray, true);
        preview.addView(drawView);

    } else {
        preview.removeView(drawView);
        drawView = new DrawView(this, null, false);
        preview.addView(drawView);

    }
```

on this class where it will draw the the circle on the mouth area. After the circle change to green, it will call another activity that is Dismiss.java class.

```
public class DrawView extends SurfaceView {
    public FaceData []mFaceArray;
    boolean _inFrame;
    private Paint mouthBrush = new Paint();
    private Paint rectBrush = new Paint();
    public Point mouth;
    Rect mFaceRect;
    AlarmService A;
    AlarmScreen B;
    Paint paint = new Paint();
}

public DrawView(Context context,FaceData []faceArray, boolean inFrame){
    super(context);
    setWillNotDraw(false);
    mFaceArray = faceArray;
    _inFrame = inFrame;
}

protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    if(_inFrame){
        for(int i = 0; i<mFaceArray.length; i++){
             setCircleColor(mFaceArray[i], mouthBrush);
             canvas.drawCircle(mFaceArray[i].mouth.x, mFaceArray[i].mouth.y, 20f, mouthBrush);  
        }
    }else{
        canvas.drawColor(0, Mode.CLEAR);
    }
}

private void setCircleColor(FaceData faceData, Paint rectBrush) {
    if(faceData.getSmileValue()<80){
        mouthBrush.setColor(Color.RED);
    }else{
        mouthBrush.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        startActivity(getContext());
    }
}

public void startActivity(Context mContext){
    Intent intent = new Intent(mContext,Dismiss.class);   
    mContext.startActivity(intent);  
}
```

this is the activity class where I should dismiss the alarm, by calling stopAlarm() method from AlarmScreen.java class, the alarm is dismissed and unfortunately application is stops here. I'm new on this field, I don't know much about why the error occur. Can somebody help me?

```
public class Dismiss extends Activity {

    public static Activity AlarmScreen;
    private MediaPlayer mPlayer;

    AlarmService A;
    AlarmScreen B;
    AlarmRing C;

    @Override
    Protected void onCreate (final Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        this.setContentView(R.layout.dismiss);

        Button dismissButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.dismiss);
        dismissButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                B.stopAlarm();
                finish();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know how to show the logcat because I'm still new, but here it is.

```
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323): Process: com.trigg.alarmclock, PID: 31323
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323): java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at com.smileclock.Dismiss$1.onClick(Dismiss.java:61)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4569)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18553)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
06-03 19:40:10.400: E/AndroidRuntime(31323):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 19:40:11.750: I/Process(31323): Sending signal. PID: 31323 SIG: 9
06-03 19:40:11.860: E/MediaPlayer-JNI(32419): QCMediaPlayer mediaplayer NOT present
06-03 19:40:11.900: D/AndroidRuntime(32419): Shutting down VM
06-03 19:40:11.900: W/dalvikvm(32419): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41613d88)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419): Process: com.trigg.alarmclock, PID: 32419
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start service com.smileclock.AlarmService@447f7488 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2767)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:144)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1343)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:212)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5135)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:877)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:693)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.content.Intent.putExtras(Intent.java:6134)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at com.smileclock.AlarmService.onStartCommand(AlarmService.java:21)
06-03 19:40:11.900: E/AndroidRuntime(32419):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2750)
```

Comment: That's a lot of code, which is good, but we're missing the vital piece of diagnostic information, the Logcat stacktrace.

Comment: i'll already put the logcat. hope you can help. - @AndrewFielden

Answer (score 0):

From the code that you posted, the following line will be throwing a null pointer exception because your code doesn't appear to initialise `B`

```
B.stopAlarm();
```

If you want to call this method on the `AlarmScreen` class you must intialise `B` to refer to an object of that type. You could pass an `AlarmScreen` object into the constructor of class `Dismiss`

Alternatively, you could take out the call to `B.stopAlarm()` from the `Dismiss` class and call it from the parent Activity, which probably does have a valid reference to `AlarmScreen`.